# Outlook - CreateDispatch Exception

Tags: c++, events, outlook

I'm trying to capture some Outlook events (It's a separate application not an Add-In). For that reason I have a class called CApplication defined as : `class CApplication : public COleDispatchDriver` and a class called CAppEventListener  : `class CAppEventListener : public IDispatch`. I'm getting an exception at `CreateDispatch` method

```
m_pAppEventListener = new CAppEventListener();
m_pAppEventListener->CheckOutlookInProcess();
COleException l_oleExcep;

if(!m_pAppEventListener->m_OutlookApplicationInternal.CreateDispatch( _T("Outlook.Application" ),&l_oleExcep))
{
    CString szMsg;
    szMsg.Format( _T("CreateDispatch() failed with error 0x%08lx"), l_oleExcep.m_sc );
    AfxMessageBox( szMsg, MB_SETFOREGROUND );
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the message box that shows the exception code. Does anybody knows where could it come from?

[image]

Comment: That is CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE, "Server execution failed".  Something very wrong with Outlook, make sure you can start it by hand.  Make sure it isn't because you've already got a hundred copies running.

Comment: @hans yes, I can start it manually and I got only one instance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE I usually raised if the security contexts of your app and Outlook are different.

Is your app running a regular GUI app or a task/service? Is either app running with elevated security privileges (Run As Administrator)?

Comment: It's an MFC app but I'm not using a GUI, output is written in a file. I tried running it as an administrator but I couldn't see any difference

Comment: @Dimtry I've noticed that when I run my app in system session it works. I think you were right, it's about security privileges but would you please give me more explanations. I want to create an installer for my app, what configuration should I set so that the application works without any pevious intervention. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean your code runs in the installer security context (which is a service)? Do not touch the Outlook Object Model in an installer. Whatever you need to do, do it when your app/addin/etc. runs for the very first time.

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough. As I said before, I had to add more security privileges to my application in order to make it work (I checked "total control" in the application property). Now I want to create an installer for my application, and I want the installer to set the needed privileges for my application so that users won't have to configure them themselves. Hope you understood what I'm doing.

Comment: If you request any special privileges, you will not be able to connect to the running instance of Outlook since the security contexts are different.